# Docker Compose postgres 9.6 initialize database

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am trying to populate a docker postgres database using the tables created by Spring boot. My docker-compose file is:

```
version: '2'

services:

  asset-management:
    image: asset-management:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://rfid-postgres:5432/rfid_database
      - DB_USERNAME=postgres
      - DB_PASSWORD=password
      - server.port=8080
    depends_on:
      - rfid-postgres

  rfid-postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=rfid_database
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - ./initial_data.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/initial_data.sql
      - ./postgresql_data:/var/lib/postgresql

volumes:
  postgresql_data:
```

In my initial_data.sql file I have many INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO public.transaction_type VALUES (1, 'In');
INSERT INTO public.transaction_type VALUES (2, 'Out');
INSERT INTO public.transaction_type VALUES (3, 'Sale');
```

When i run docker-compose up, i do see that the tables are created by asset-management and the initial_data.sql is copied. However, the statements inside it are not executed.

Comment: Does the `postgresql_data` host directory start out totally empty?  Does the `initial_data.sql` file also contain the required `CREATE TABLE` statements?  Are there any interesting things in either container's logs?

Comment: ahh silly me! i think the problem is because my spring boot app creates the tables. The spring boot app depends on postgresql service hence when the postgresql starts there is no tables. i should have moved the init_data.sql to the other service